# ifstream position in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to write a simple UTF-8 decoder for my assignment. I'm fairly new with C++ so bear with me here...

I have to determine whether the encoding is valid or not, and output the value of the UTF-8 character in hexadecimal in either case. Say that I have read the first byte and used this first byte to determine the number of bytes in this UTF8 character. The problem is that after I read the first byte, i'm having trouble setting the ifstream position back one byte and read the whole UTF-8 character. I've tried seekg() and putback(), but i always get BUS error or some weird output that's not my test data. Please help, thanks.

Even though i can use peek() for the first byte, but i still have to read the following bytes to determine whether the encoding is valid or not. The problem of setting back the stream position is still there.

Comment: It might help to post a small piece of code demonstrating the error that you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use peek() to read the first byte instead.  seekg() should work to rewind, but a BUS error is usually caused by your code breaking alignment issues, which points to you doing something else evil in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have to seek back? Can't you simply read the rest of the UTF-8 sequence, after knowing how many more octets you're expecting?

Comment: i have to output the whole character in hex value.

Comment: OK, so you already got the first byte. Read the rest, and output all. I don't understand why you need to seek back.

Answer (score 1):

I would read the next byte directly and add it to what I got. As Ates Goral said. It is cleaner IMHO.

Anyway, You could move the stream pointer using `seekg()`:

```
char byte = 0;
unsigned  int character = 0; // on every usage
ifstream file("test.txt", ios::binary);

file.get(byte);
......
file.seekg(-1, ios::cur); // cur == current position
file.get(
    reinterpret_cast<char*>(&character),
    numberOfBytesAndNullTerminator);

cout << hex << character;
```

Beware that `get()` in the second case writes `'\0'` at the end of `character`. So you have to give it the required number of bytes including the null terminator. So, if you want to read two bytes `==> numberOfBytesAndNullTerminator = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to put the character back but istream::unget() or istream::putback() should do what you want. Look them up in your compiler's documentation.

Answer (score -1):

please look up :

```
ifstream::seekg()
ifstream::teellg()
```